# Failed to fetch because of size mismatch error while upgrading

Tags: apt, updates

When I try to install updates from the update manager it says:

```
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-3.0.0-13-generic_3.0.0-13.22_i386.deb  
Size mismatch
```

I have tried several times and through terminal too but the size mismatch repeats itself there too. What is this size mismatch error?

I also tried `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`, but the error comes again.

```
Failed to fetch
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xserver-xorg-video-intel/xserver-xorg-video-intel_2.15.901-1ubuntu2.1_i386.deb  
Size mismatch  
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

in terminal and then

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 3):

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --fix-missing`

Answer (score 2):

There may be a problem with the package on the repository's end. I suggest you wait a day or two, check for updates, and then install the updates again later. That should solve the problem.